# Why is my <Select> html element not updating properly after changing its content?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I have a simple select element, which of course contains a bunch of option elements.

I'm making a simple search function in a text input field, which basically hides all option elements inside the select element that doesn't contain the search text. This works fine.

BUT, after I have hidden the necessary option elements and only shown the ones I want, there's a strange bug with the dropdown. When I click the dropdown (select element) after the changes have been made (hiding and showing option elements), it's empty on the first click. But if I click it again, it's updated correctly with the right visible option elements.

I've searched and searched and tried 20 different things to solve this annoying little issue, but I can't figure out why I have to click my dropdown twice before the changes are visible?

Can someone shed some light on this or offer a solution?

Here's some code, the option elements are dynamically created somewhere else  but the code works fine for hiding/showing the option elements:

```js
var timeoutId2;
$(document).on("input propertychange change", ".searchField", function() {
  clearTimeout(timeoutId2);

  var searchInput = $(this).val();

  if (searchInput == "") {
    $(".monsterOption").css("display", "block");
  } else {
    $(".monsterOption").css("display", "none");
    timeoutId2 = setTimeout(function() {
      $(".monsterOption").each(function(i, ele) {
        var monstername = $(this).data("monstername");
        if (monstername.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchInput.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
          $(".monsterDropdown").val(monstername);
          $(this).css("display", "block");
        }
      });
    }, 300);

  }
});
```

```html
<input class="searchField" type="text" placeholder="search here">

<select class="monsterDropdown">
  <option class="monsterOption" data-monstername="Car 1">Car 1</option>
  <option class="monsterOption" data-monstername="Car 2">Car 2</option>
  <option class="monsterOption" data-monstername="Plane 1">Plane 1</option>
  <option class="monsterOption" data-monstername="Boat 1">Boat 1</option>
  <option class="monsterOption" data-monstername="Boat 2">Boat 2</option>
</select>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: @ObedMarsh your code literally has a delay in it. that is what `setTimeout` does

Comment: As you can see from this [extremely minimal test case](https://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/nxu82ke5/), one is able to hide and show option elements in a select list with instant updates, clicking twice not required.  So there is a bug in your code, meaning the code is not working correctly.  If there is no bug, then its working correctly.  Your hostility is not appreciated.  That said, I'm going to edit your js fiddle into the question, because as noted by [mre], as was already linked to you above, all details relevant to the question need to be in the question itself due to the fact of link rot.

Comment: @ObedMarsh for somebody who is looking for help you are not very nice

Comment: @Alex Well, it was pretty obvious what I'm doing with the timeout in my code example. So implying I don't know there's a 300ms delay is kind of insulting.

Comment: @ObedMarsh Pretty sure Alex was referring to your comments before the comment you refer to was made.

Comment: To whomever asked about this. The timeout is there so it doesn't load the script after every single button click, but instead waits until you let go of the keyboard. That's the purpose of it, to avoid excessive loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `setTimeout` to show the results after `300` milliseconds, creating the illusion that the results only show up after expanding the `select` the second time.

Removing it should work:

```js
var timeoutId2;
$(document).on("input propertychange change", ".searchField", function() {
  clearTimeout(timeoutId2);

  var searchInput = $(this).val();

  if (searchInput == "") {
    $(".monsterOption").css("display", "block");
  } else {
    $(".monsterOption").css("display", "none");
    $(".monsterOption").each(function(i, ele) {
      var monstername = $(this).data("monstername");
      if (monstername.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchInput.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
        $(".monsterDropdown").val(monstername);
        $(this).css("display", "block");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<input class="searchField" type="text" placeholder="search here">

<select class="monsterDropdown">
  <option class="monsterOption" data-monstername="Car 1">Car 1</option>
  <option class="monsterOption" data-monstername="Car 2">Car 2</option>
  <option class="monsterOption" data-monstername="Plane 1">Plane 1</option>
  <option class="monsterOption" data-monstername="Boat 1">Boat 1</option>
  <option class="monsterOption" data-monstername="Boat 2">Boat 2</option>
</select>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: @ObedMarsh this doesn't have the problem you mentioned. I tried your jfiddle and saw what you meant.  This code snippet doesn't have that problem anymore.  Why would you need to use `setTimeout` anyway?

Comment: @ObedMarsh Are you sure?  Testing the code here, and the code in this answer, the bug is not reproduceable.  The code works without having to click it twice.  In your jsfiddle/stack snippet(how your code currently shows in your question) example, simply waiting 300 ms is enough for your code to work.  So if this answer doesn't solve your question, the onus is on you to make a test case that clearly demonstrates your problem.  To repeat in case the prior sentence is too vague, your js fiddle doesn't show this double-click-required problem you talk about in your question.

Comment: I made a mistake when I implemented the code into my project to test your solution and it didn't work, corrected it now and it seems your answer solves the problem.

Comment: @Barmar That's correct the explanation is wrong, but removing the timeout DOES solve the issue. It doesn't matter if you wait 300 ms you still have to click twice when the timeout is present no matter what.

Comment: @Alex The timeout is there so it doesn't load the script after every single button click, but instead waits until you let go of the keyboard. That's the purpose of it, to avoid excessive loading.